# Output from a PDO statement

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

Can anyone spot where I might be going wrong with the following code?

```
<?php

    //MySQL Database Connect
    require 'config.php';
    $unitFrom = "kilogram";
    $unitTo = "gram";
    $units = "9000";

    try{
    require 'config.php';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('CALL sp_get_conversion(:in_unit_from, :in_unit_to, :in_amount, @out_amount)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':in_unit_from',$unitFrom,PDO::PARAM_STR,4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':in_unit_to',$unitTo,PDO::PARAM_STR,4000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':in_amount',$units,PDO::PARAM_STR,4000);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();

    $conversion = $dbh->query( "SELECT @out_amount" )->fetchColumn(); 
    echo $conversion;

    }   
?>
```

When I run the stored procedure in phpmyadmin it works fine but nothing is echoed out when I try the code above.

Thanks

Comment: No need to require the same file twice. Using `require_once("config.php");` in this case would ensure that a second `require_once` would only require it if it hasn't been required already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be in the `try` block:

```
$conversion = $dbh->query( "SELECT @out_amount" )->fetchColumn(); 
echo $conversion;
```

You currently have it in the `catch` block so it will get executed only if there is an exception is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try handling your error as dictated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). It's how I've always worked with PDO issues.

Comment: Whether exceptions are thrown (the preferred method IMHO) is dependent on the setting of PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE after the database connection is established (which I assume the OP is already setting).